# Snowflake ignores statement in where clause when comparing timestamps

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, compare, equality

I'm building an SCD type 2 in Snowflake, but it ignores the where clause in which is comparison between `to_timestamp` and `expiry_date`. Expiry_date is a variable that is set to '9999-08-17 07:31:29.901000000' (as infinity) and To_timestamp is a column in table. I want to query only the rows that have to_timestamp set to infinity (they are still active) but Snowflake seems to ignore this part of where clause. Below is some of the code (it should update the rows that are expired - that means change their `to_timestamp` to current time. and it does but it does to rows with timestamps of all kind - it ignores last line).

```sql
SET EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ = '9999-08-17 07:31:29.901000000';
SET CURRENT_DATE_NTZ = TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());


UPDATE CUSTOMER_TARGET CT
SET CT.TO_TIMESTAMP = $CURRENT_DATE_NTZ
FROM POC.SNOWFLAKE_POC.CUSTOMER_STAGE CS
WHERE CT.C_CUSTOMER_ID = CS.C_CUSTOMER_ID
    AND (CT.C_FIRST_NAME <> CS.C_FIRST_NAME OR CT.C_LAST_NAME <> CS.C_LAST_NAME OR CT.C_BIRTH_YEAR 
    <> CS.C_BIRTH_YEAR OR CT.C_BIRTH_COUNTRY <> CS.C_BIRTH_COUNTRY OR CT.C_LAST_REVIEW_DATE<>CS.C_LAST_REVIEW_DATE)
    AND CT.TO_TIMESTAMP = $EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ;
```

I have two of these update statements (one for updates and one for deletes) and a merge statement for inserts. And it ignores the comparison in every single one, updating the rows that have `to_timestamp` set to something like `2021-08-24 07:11:53.510000000`. I've tried every combination possible (`between ... and ...`, `>= ... <=`, `<=`, `>=`, comparing in `case` statement of update, ...) - nothing. What could be the cause/solution?

Comment: I suppose that "ignoring" means that no rows match the filter, and not that too many rows are affected. Why do you not set the 'infinity' value to '9999-12-31 23:59:59' for all concerned, currently active, rows, and use that also for comparison? Alternatively, you could use a Boolean `is_current` that is only true for the current ones, and set both  `to_timestamp` and `is_current` to the right values in the update process.

Comment: Is the column actually called "to_timestamp"? Using the name of a function as a column name is not a great design, it's going to make your code more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL does not have any issues with the filters (ORs are surrounded by the brackets etc). I assume that you have checked the execution profile, and did not see your filter (CT.TO_TIMESTAMP = '9999-08-17 07:31:29.901000000'). In this case, all rows in the target table should have this value in the column TO_TIMESTAMP.

I highly recommend you check the data first. If you are running multiple UPDATE/MERGE commands, you may miss that the data has already updated with this value.

Answer (score 0):

As we do not know the structure of `CUSTOMER_TARGET` I would suggest to explicitly set the data type of `EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ` variable to match the column data type:

```
SET EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ = '9999-08-17 07:31:29.901000000';
SELECT $EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ;
DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

[image]

to:

```
-- TIMESTAMP_NTZ as an example
SET EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ = '9999-08-17 07:31:29.901000000'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ;  
SELECT $EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ;
DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
```

By doing that way there are no "implicit conversions" involved in the process.

[image]

---

Another advice is usage of `IS DISTINCT FROM` instead of `<>`. `IS DISTINCT FROM` is NULL safe, which is important if columns are defined as nullable.

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_TARGET CT
SET CT.TO_TIMESTAMP = $CURRENT_DATE_NTZ
FROM POC.SNOWFLAKE_POC.CUSTOMER_STAGE CS
WHERE CT.C_CUSTOMER_ID = CS.C_CUSTOMER_ID
    AND (CT.C_FIRST_NAME IS DISTINCT FROM CS.C_FIRST_NAME 
         OR CT.C_LAST_NAME IS DISTINCT FROM CS.C_LAST_NAME 
         OR CT.C_BIRTH_YEAR IS DISTINCT FROM CS.C_BIRTH_YEAR 
         OR CT.C_BIRTH_COUNTRY IS DISTINCT FROM CS.C_BIRTH_COUNTRY 
         OR CT.C_LAST_REVIEW_DATE IS DISTINCT FROM CS.C_LAST_REVIEW_DATE)
    AND CT.TO_TIMESTAMP = $EXPIRY_DATE_NTZ;
```